# FIX UNKNOWN facts keep being asserted implicitly in CLIPS

Tags: clips

Fix implicit assert of facts

The deftemplate and defrules

```
(deftemplate Fuels  "Identifying characteristics"
   (slot appearance
      (type SYMBOL)
      (allowed-symbols clear amber brownish-red yellow-tint brown-with-green-tint yellowish-green)
   )
   (slot smell
      (type SYMBOL)
      (allowed-symbols strong-odour strong-lingering-odour  cooking-oil  burnt-popcorn)
   )
   (slot touch
      (type SYMBOL)
      (allowed-symbols oily-feel waxy  cold  slippery)
   )
)

(defrule Petrol  "Identifying characteristics"
   (Fuels (appearance brownish-red|yellow-tint)
          (smell strong-odour)
          (touch cold)
   )  
   =>
   (printout t "It's petrol that is leaking" crlf
               "If leak is caused by something other than over filling the tank, do NOT drive the car." crlf
               "Fuel leaks are very dangerous and potentially explosive."crlf
               "Call a mechanic if you find a fuel leak in your car"crlf
   )
)

(defrule Diesel "Identifying characteristics"
   (Fuels (appearance brown-with-green-tint|yellowish-green)
          (smell strong-lingering-odour)  
          (touch oily-feel|waxy)
   )
   =>
   (printout t "It's diesel that is leaking" crlf
               "If leak is caused by something other than overfilling the tank, do NOT drive the car." crlf
               "Fuel leaks are very dangerous and potentially explosive."crlf
               "Call a mechanic if you find a fuel leak in your car"crlf
              
   )
)

(defrule Bio-fuel  "Identifying characteristics"
   (Fuels (appearance clear|amber) 
          (smell cooking-oil|burnt-popcorn)
          (touch slippery) 
   )
   =>
   (printout t crlf 
             "It's bio-fuel that is leaking" crlf
             "If leak is caused by something other than overfilling the tank,DO NOT! drive the car." crlf 
             "Fuel leaks are very dangerous and potentially explosive."crlf 
             "Call a mechanic if you find a fuel leak in your car."crlf
   )
)
```

When facts command is used this is returned

```
f-1     (Fuels (appearance brownish-red) (smell strong-odor) (touch oily-feel))
f-2     (Fuels (appearance clear) (smell strong-odor) (touch oily-feel))
f-3     (Fuels (appearance clear) (smell strong-odor) (touch cold))
```

even though this was asserted :

```
(Fuels (appearance brownish-red) (smell strong-odour) (touch cold))
```

Help fix this

Comment: It's not possible for the code you've posted to produce this result. You've left something out in describing your problem.

Comment: this is the full  knowledge base

Comment: when match is used neither defrule Petrol ,Diesel or Bio-fuel is activated

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with this code, but there's also no way that it could produce facts f-2 and f-3 as you've shown in your question.

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate Fuels  "Identifying characteristics"
   (slot appearance
      (type SYMBOL)
      (allowed-symbols clear amber brownish-red yellow-tint brown-with-green-tint yellowish-green)
   )
   (slot smell
      (type SYMBOL)
      (allowed-symbols strong-odour strong-lingering-odour  cooking-oil  burnt-popcorn)
   )
   (slot touch
      (type SYMBOL)
      (allowed-symbols oily-feel waxy  cold  slippery)
   )
)
CLIPS> 
(defrule Petrol  "Identifying characteristics"
   (Fuels (appearance brownish-red|yellow-tint)
          (smell strong-odour)
          (touch cold)
   )  
   =>
   (printout t "It's petrol that is leaking" crlf
               "If leak is caused by something other than over filling the tank, do NOT drive the car." crlf
               "Fuel leaks are very dangerous and potentially explosive."crlf
               "Call a mechanic if you find a fuel leak in your car"crlf
   )
)
CLIPS> 
(defrule Diesel "Identifying characteristics"
   (Fuels (appearance brown-with-green-tint|yellowish-green)
          (smell strong-lingering-odour)  
          (touch oily-feel|waxy)
   )
   =>
   (printout t "It's diesel that is leaking" crlf
               "If leak is caused by something other than overfilling the tank, do NOT drive the car." crlf
               "Fuel leaks are very dangerous and potentially explosive."crlf
               "Call a mechanic if you find a fuel leak in your car"crlf
              
   )
)
CLIPS> 
(defrule Bio-fuel  "Identifying characteristics"
   (Fuels (appearance clear|amber) 
          (smell cooking-oil|burnt-popcorn)
          (touch slippery) 
   )
   =>
   (printout t crlf 
             "It's bio-fuel that is leaking" crlf
             "If leak is caused by something other than overfilling the tank,DO NOT! drive the car." crlf 
             "Fuel leaks are very dangerous and potentially explosive."crlf 
             "Call a mechanic if you find a fuel leak in your car."crlf
   )
)
CLIPS> (assert (Fuels (appearance brownish-red) (smell strong-odour) (touch cold)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      Petrol: f-1
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (run)
It's petrol that is leaking
If leak is caused by something other than over filling the tank, do NOT drive the car.
Fuel leaks are very dangerous and potentially explosive.
Call a mechanic if you find a fuel leak in your car
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (Fuels (appearance brownish-red) (smell strong-odour) (touch cold))
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS>
```